# How to access radio button within same group in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I put a couple of radio button in same group in following way:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="ID11" Text="Text1" GroupName="G1" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="ID12" Text="Text2" GroupName="G1" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="ID13" Text="Text3" GroupName="G1" runat="server" />
```

IDs for each radio button generated dynamically. 
then I want to access those radio button in javascript. How to go through those radio buttons without use each ID?

Comment: @Xander indeed I had jQuery on my mind

Answer (score 1):

you should be using a RadioButtonList

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="rblOption" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Yes" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="No" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and you can get the value using something like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rblOption= '<%= rbList.ClientID %>';
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, this is always going to generate to

```
<input type="radio" />
```

controls

imagine that they are a form with id 'form' you'd do something like:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var controls = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var control in controls){
   if(control.getAttribute('type') == 'radio'{
      //control will be a radiobutton
   }
}
```